# MVC 4 - getting a 404 on a certain area's controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-areas

My problem is regarding setting up my app's access for internal users and external users.

Based on [MS TechKB: AREAS in ASP.NET](http://mstechkb.blogspot.com/2010/10/areas-in-aspnet-mvc-20.html) I went with AREAS. I have an `Areas/Internal` and `Areas/External`. `Areas/External` has the actual functionality and controllers for the app. All `Areas/Internal` does is check server variables and sets your identity as your domain name if it checks out in active directory.

The problem is, I can get to the `Areas/External` controllers/pages just fine but when I try to browse to the `Areas/Internal` area controller I get a 404. My controller is named `Intranet` (excluding the "Controller" in the name) and this is what my `InternalAreaRegistration.cs` file looks like:

```
    public override void RegisterArea(System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Internal_default",
            "Intranet/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }

    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Internal";
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why I would be getting a 404 on the internal controllers?

Comment: how would the routing works without controller?

Comment: the external routing uses the standard {controller}/{action}/{id} I don't know if that answers your question

Comment: but this line new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }); does not

Comment: The line you're talking about is just for internal because it has "Intranet" hardcoded above it as the controller name. It's the external route that includes the {controller} and defaults it to "Home".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are missing controller segment  after Area in the code you wrote above. It should be something like:

```
        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Internal_default",
                "Intranet/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "Your Controller Namespace" }
            );
        }
```

A related question at below link is answered, hope that will help too:
[Controller with same name as an area - Asp.Net MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777880/controller-with-same-name-as-an-area-asp-net-mvc4/20008812#20008812)